# Redirect to a certain page if the user has a missing information, ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to force the logged in user to fill in their personal information. So I need to redirect the user to the information page. But I want to do it from another module, not in action methods.

Any suggestion how I can achieve this in ASP.NET Core (2.0)?

Comment: What do you mean _do it from another module_?

Comment: Most likely, you'd want to use custom middleware or a custom action filter. However, your question is too broad. Attempt a solution, and then you can ask about any specific issues you encounter.

Comment: Did you solve this some how? Would be interested in your solution.